# Hard inequality in contest for regional Olympiad 2011

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let a,b,c strictly positive numbers.
Prove that
$$5(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a})+12 \geq 3(\sqrt{\frac{a+8b}{c}}+\sqrt{\frac{b+8c}{a}}+\sqrt{\frac{c+8a}{b}})$$

I have tried to use tangent method but seems useless. And I have tried Cauchy with no results...

Comment: There is a nice proof by AM-GM only,but until you show your work I may not be able to help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Cauchy-Schwarz, we have $$\left(\sum\sqrt{\frac{a + 8b}c}\right)^2 \leq \left(\sum \frac b c \right)\left(\sum \frac {a + 8b} b\right).$$

If we write $X$ for $\sum\frac b c$ and $Y$ for $\sum\sqrt{\frac{a + 8b}c}$, then the above inequality translates to $$Y^2 \leq X(24 + X).$$

Therefore $$9Y^2 \leq 9X^2 + 216X \leq 9X^2 + 216X + (4X - 12)^2 = (5X + 12)^2.$$

Comment: It seems Cauchy is not working in the first relation you wrote.

Comment: The [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) reads $\left(\sum u_i v_i\right)^2 \leq \left(\sum u_i^2\right)\left(\sum v_i^2\right)$. Now put $u_1 = \sqrt{ \frac b c}, v_1 = \sqrt{\frac{a + 8b}b}$, etc.